# After installing new 3 position fan switch, fan doesn't turn

Tags: ceiling-fan, bedroom

After installing new 3 position fan switch, fan doesn't turn and motor hums in forward position but doesn't turn, nothing in reverse position

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring inside the fan, and what make/model this fan is?

Comment: It is an old Hunter with hard wired 4 wires

Comment: Please add the info to the original post.